# how to display the directory listing of an webserver in iphone native application

Tags: iphone

How to fetch files and directories names on iphone native application from the web server?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *urlData;
NSString *urlString   = @"mysite.com/myfile";

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval: 10.0]; 

NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:nil]; 
if (connection) { 
    urlData = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request
}
[connection release];
```